# LUA wireshark dissector - combine data from 2 UDP packets

Tags: lua, udp, wireshark-dissector

I have fixed size (lets say 100) protocol, based on the **UDP**.
The protocol contains the header which indicates where the first **complete** sub-message is located (location 5 in the buffer). Sub-messages starts at location 10 and may vary in sizes.

Also, following scenario may occur.
Packet contains some some sub-messages where each one of them is dealt separately. However, it maybe that one of the sub-messages will be greater than the rest of the whole packet length (lets say that this sub-message length is starting at location 95 and its length is 12 bytes) and therefore the sub-message would be split into 2 packets as shown below - first part would be in packet x (5 bytes) and the rest in packet x+1 (7 bytes). 
In such case, in message x+1 first sub-message location indicator will be 17 instead of 10.

[image: Protocol structure]

Any way, as the sub-message N is split, my applicative SW can't handle till the whole sub-message would be available and therefore I'd like to dissect packet N (N1+N2) in packet x+1.

Currently I have a dissector which can handle packets where the sub-message is not filling the whole buffer (i.e. sub-messages are less than 100 Bytes) or in case of packet x, it will parse only the 5 bytes. in case of packet x+1, it will start with sub-message 1 and will skip the N2.

I need some assistance with implementing the combining N1 with packet x+1 (except the header) so that it can be processed accordingly. I've found that I have to use the ByteArray to store the data between packet x and x+1 but getting lost with the implementation.
Some code example with explanations would be appropriated.

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far. If it's too long for a post, link to it.

Comment: @RossJacobs unfortunately I can't do this as it is in my internal network.